# Saving a bitmap with the "DateTaken" attribute

Tags: c#

**The aim**

I am writing an automated image resizing app for a specific job. Images are taken with a smart phone, uploaded to a folder, then my application runs and resizes all the files, and saves them into an output folder.

**The issue**

The image resizing works fine, the problem is that the "DateTaken" attribute is lost when the resized file is saved.

**The Code**

I have managed to get the value of the original file's DateTaken Attribute and put it into a DateTime object. I am trying to find ways to save this data back to the original file, but I couldn't find any examples online, other than to add 7 hours to the DateTaken attribute.

```
    private static void Resize(string imageFile, string outputFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
        {

            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);


            DateTime DateTaken = GetDateTakenFromImage(imageFile);
            newImage.Save(outputFile);

        }
    }
```

Comment: DateTaken is a property held in a photos Exif data. Google around .net Exif and you should find a solution.

Comment: @PhillipH I've had a good look for half the day, but I couldn't find any clear examples, only people trying and failing to do the same. This person seems to be close to getting a working solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6263b6b-24bf-409e-bf47-2b3762c57cc2/copy-all-exif-from-source-to-target-jpeg-image?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: You are saving the file in the PNG format.  EXIF metadata goes with the JPEG format.  Use the Save() overload that lets you specify the ImageFormat.  Recompressing JPEG files is not a great idea btw.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. The files save as .jpeg. Recompressing is fine in my use case.

Comment: Added codec info which reduces the file size almost 20x on some images, but date taken attribute doesn't get copied.